# PHP Simple HTML DOM - get text from element without css class

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

How to get content of an element, only if element doesn't have class?
I'm using **PHP Simple HTML DOM** to get content from external page.

```
$html = file_get_html('someurl/page.html');

foreach($html->find('code') as $element) {
    echo $element->plaintext . '<br>';
}
```

I get content from all `<code>` tags. And I don't want content from `<code class="smth">`, I want content only from `<code>` without any class.
From Simple DOM manual:

```
// Find all element which class=foo
$ret = $html->find('.foo');

// Remove a attribute, set it's value as null! 
$e->href = null;

// Determine whether a attribute exist? 
if(isset($e->href)) 
        echo 'href exist!';
```

I tried

```
if(isset($e->class)) {
        echo $element->plaintext. '<br>';
    }
```

But this is searching only classes in output (probably?), not in external page. So it echo nothing.

///// Edit

```
$html->find('.className')
```

This line return element only if it's not `<code>` tag???? Div and p works fine, but not code???

Any clue?
Thanks

Comment: I even know unwanted class name, if that's helpful.

Comment: Use $element instead of $e.

Comment: Thanks, but no output still. Strange, I can get div with some class from external page, but can not get code tag with class??

Comment: Can you post a part of your html input code please to test against it...

Comment: external page is here [link](http://getuikit.com/docs/grid.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `I get content from all <code> tags. And I don't want content from <code class="smth">, I want content only from <code> without any class.`

You can use `[!attribute]` wich matches elements that don't have the specified attribute... In your case you should try `code[!class]`

As example, here's a working code getting all anchors not having the `target` attribute:

```
// includes Simple HTML DOM Parser
include "simple_html_dom.php";

$text = '<div>
            <a href="#" >OK 1</a>
            <a href="#" target="_blank">Not needed</a>
            <a href="#" >OK 2</a>
            <a href="#" target="_blank">Not needed</a>
            <a href="#" >OK 3</a>
            <a href="#" target="_blank">Not needed</a>
            <a href="#" >OK 4</a>
        </div>';

//Create a DOM object
$html = new simple_html_dom();
// Load HTML from a string
$html->load($text);

// Get all anchors not having target as attribute
$anchors = $html->find('div a[!target]');

// loop and print nodes content
foreach( $anchors as $i => $anchor ) {

    echo "$i => ".$anchor->outertext."<br/>";
}

// Clear dom object
$html->clear(); 
unset($html);
```

*OUTPUT:*

```
0 => OK 1
1 => OK 2
2 => OK 3
3 => OK 4
```

[`Working DEMO`](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/myc-g7n)

**Edit:**

After inspection of the raw code, here's a way to get the wanted parts... Just to give you the idea, of course you can still improve it:

```
// includes Simple HTML DOM Parser
include "simple_html_dom.php";

$url = 'http://getuikit.com/docs/grid.html';

//Create a DOM object
$html = new simple_html_dom();
// Load HTML from a string
$html->load_file($url);

// Get all nodes with "tm-article-subtitle"...
$nodes = $html->find('.tm-article-subtitle');

// loop and print nodes content
foreach( $nodes as $i => $node ) {

    // Filter only those containing "Markup"
    if (stripos($node->plaintext, "Markup") !== false) {
        echo "<pre>$i => ";

        // The wanted code in pre can be 1 or 2 position far from "Markup"
        if(stripos($node->next_sibling()->tag, "pre") !== false)
            echo htmlentities($node->next_sibling()->outertext);

        elseif(stripos($node->next_sibling()->next_sibling()->tag, "pre") !== false)
            echo htmlentities($node->next_sibling()->next_sibling()->outertext);

        echo "</pre>";
    }

}

// Clear dom object
$html->clear(); 
unset($html);
```

*OUPUT*

```
1 => <pre><code>&lt;div class="uk-grid"&gt;...
5 => <pre><code>&lt;div class="uk-grid"&gt;...
8 => <pre><code>&lt;div class="uk-grid uk-g...
10 => <pre><code>&lt;div class="uk-grid"&gt...
12 => <pre><code>&lt;div class="uk-grid" data-uk-grid-match&gt;...&lt;/div&gt;</code></pre>
14 => <pre><code>&lt;div class="uk-grid" data-uk-grid-match=...
16 => <pre><code>&lt;ul class="uk-grid" data-uk-grid-margin&gt;     &lt;!-- Th
```

[`Working DEMO`](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/abv-4rd)

Comment: Somehow I can't access `<code>` class. Even `$html->find('.codeClass')` won't work. It works for div or p.

Comment: This works in a fiddle, but not if content is loaded from external page. There has to be something with that page.  [link](http://getuikit.com/docs/grid.html)  .Thanks

Comment: In the [LINK](http://getuikit.com/docs/grid.html) you gave above, no `code` tag has a `class` attribute, so that behaviour is normal... [`DEMO`](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/mv9-tyj)

Comment: I'll accept this answer, something other is issue here. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, the isssue is that the RAW code doesnt contain any `class="xml"` wich is added using JavaScript (`ctrl+U` to see the raw source code)... Even without using that class, there's a way to get the wanted code... I'll update my answer shortly...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41769/discussion-between-enissay-and-lima-fil)